# Unity SMTP SEnd Email IOException: Connection closed

Tags: c#, android, email, unity-game-engine, smtp

I'm trying to send an email through unity, my code is as follows:

```
public static void sendLogByEmail(){
            Debug.Log ("Send Log By Email");
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("mail@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Log de la " + Session.tipoUsuario + "-" + Session.idTipoUsuario + " de " + PaisesModel.getNombrePais();
            mail.Body = "-" + Session.tipoUsuario + ": " + Session.idTipoUsuario + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                "-Usuario: " + Session.usuario + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "-Jornada: " + Session.idJornada + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                    "-Dispositivo: " + Session.idDispositivo;

            Attachment data = new Attachment(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

            System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(filePath);
            disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath);

            mail.Attachments.Add (data);

            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpServer.Port = 465;
            smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.com", "password");
            smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;



            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                delegate(object sim, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors){
                return true;
            };

            try{
                smtpServer.Send (mail);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Debug.Log (e.GetBaseException().ToString());
            }

            mail.Dispose();
        }
```

I will send an email to the same address it's sent to. Like emailing yourself, but I'm getting the following Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Connection closed
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendCore (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendInternal (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Scripts.Controls.LogFileControl:sendLogByEmail() (at Assets/Scripts/Controls/LogFileControl.cs:169)
MyLeftMenuBar:<createProtected>m__30(MyGameObject, EventArgs) (at Assets/Scripts/Controls/MyLeftMenuBar.cs:177)
MyGameObject:OnTap()
InputHandler:handleMouseUp(Vector3)
InputHandler:handleMouseGestures()
InputHandler:Update()
```

can anyone help me out? Anyone knows if I need to install any sort of software, library or plugin for unity/android/C# so that it works? Or maybe any additional configuration (in code or outside of it) that I might be missing?

Comment: Allow gmail server to work with your app. See [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/21/gmail-starts-block-less-secure-apps-enable-access/) post.

Comment: @Programmer still getting the same error

Comment: Try another email services to see if it works.

Comment: What happens if you don't have the attachment? How big is the attachment

Comment: @MadMyche the attachment is empty right now, so a few bytes, it's a txt file. I've tried not sending the attachment and I still get the same Exception while sending only subject and body

Comment: You may want to try port 587 for TLS (465 is SSL)

Comment: @MadMyche I have ssl enabled in my code, but I'll try changing the port and use TLS

Comment: Gmail has stepped up their security.  You may be able to get your current code to function as is by allowing less secure apps (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) However OAuth2 is the new standard.  The instructions can be found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: @AdamVincent _Less Secure Apps_  was contained in the first comment. oAuth may be required for access to Google APIs, but SMTP is a protocol. Google accepts the SMTP/IMAP protocals of accepting SASL credentials that have existed since the 90s and has extended this to also allow oAuth as an alternative. Reference: [GMail IMAP and SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp)

Comment: like I'm unaware that SMTP is a protocol. Seeings how the name of it is  "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol"  OAuth2 is Google's new standard of security for it's APIs.*  That better?

Comment: @MadMyche TLS didn't work either, Adam Vincent thanks for the suggestion, however at my work we have changed to an internal email account created through goddady's secureserver, so I'll try and see what configurations I need for that mail server and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Is this solved already? for me it should work but you need to change port to 587.